# How to write one comment and publish on every post using database or plugin?

Tags: plugins, php, database, mysql

I have about `500 posts` published in WordPress now I want to add one same comment on every post. How to do the by the database. I search about it, but not a good luck. 
thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be safer to use `[wp_insert_comment()][1]` rather than manually through MySQL. WP often inserts data in multiple tables - using its core functions helps ensure that all of the data gets added in all of the right tables.

I'd suggest creating a query to pull all published posts. Then, set up a foreach loop that calls `wp_insert_comment()` on every post, thus inserting the comment on each one.